# python flair module is giving error cannot import name '_BaseLazyModule' from 'transformers.file_utils'

Tags: python, data-science, flair

```
from flair.models import TextClassifier
from flair.data import Sentence
```

I am receiving error:

> cannot import name '_BaseLazyModule' from 'transformers.file_utils'

Can anyone help me?